# How do I manage an infinite process in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a process which is an infinite loop:

```
public class MyProcess {

    public void start() {
        while (true) {
            //process
        }
    }
}
```

When I started using Spring Boot, my first approach was to get the bean from the context after the application had started and manually start the process:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);

        MyProcess myProcess = applicationContext.getBean(MyProcess.class);
        myProcess.start();
    }
}
```

This worked but did not seem like the right way of doing it, so I implemented a `CommandLineRunner`:

```
@Component
public class MyRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private MyProcess myProcess;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        this.myProcess.start();
    }
}
```

This is almost the same as before, but here the `SpringApplication#run` call never actually finishes, which seems also wrong. **Am I correct to think that?**

I then tried to manage this on my own with an `Executor`, but in order to catch any `Exception` I had to call `Future#get` which resulted in the same blocking state.

Instead of this, I am now using an `@Async` annotation on the `CommandLineRunner#run` method.

This seems to be the best solution as the application finishes starting after the task has also been started. Any `Exception` will be picked up and logged, but the backing `Executor` created by Sprint prevents the application from shutting down.

I assume there is a way of asking Spring to terminate the `Executor` so that the entire application can exit since I am managing it externally with Supervisor.

Is this the correct approach or am I missing a step? Should the application be independent and restart the process after a failure?

Answer (score 1):

Do some work in the main thread. What is wrong with calling `myProcess.start()` from `main()` without `@Async`? When you finish your job just leave loop in `MyProcess#start`

Comment: This is what I did first, but I've never seen that in any examples so I'm not sure. What would be the purpose of `CommandLineRunner` then?

Comment: @Djon I had same question. Looks like it's a way to access command line arguments in running environment with injected beans(after app is started). I use ```CommandLineRunner``` interface for command line app