# How to properly execute code in Spring Boot after an exception and let the program exit?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-boot

After thinking about how to run an infinite task in Spring Boot (see my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38719127/1460626%20question)), I decided to do this:

```
@Component
@EnableAsync
public class MyRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;

    @Async
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        try {
            infiniteLoop();
        } finally {
            this.scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

This allows the `SpringApplication#run` method to fully complete.

As part of the whole thing, I have declared a `ScheduledExecutorService` bean. My issue is that if `infiniteLoop()` throws an unexpected exception, the `Executor` will prevent the application from shunting down as it is managed externally.

Is there a better way to handle such a case? Or is this a good use of the `finally` block?

Comment: So you want that the boot application stops after unexpected exception, right? `shutdown` of the executerService wont accept new tasks but the already submitted tasks continue to run. Is this what you want?

Comment: @Patrick Yes, without the executor everything just terminates, the context is destroyed and the application stops. But once the executor is started, it has to be manually `shutdown` at some point before the application can exit gracefully, and this is the solution I came up with.

Comment: From my point of view your solution is ok. Just want to share [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11520233/3493036) with you for optional implementation after shutdown call.

Comment: @Patrick The tasks are actually really small and will always complete in a very short time, so calling `shutdown` or `shutdownNow` should be the same, but I'll have a look.